# Finding a matching keyword from a text file using python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I have a text file with following format and many such lines

```
Main keyword:Mainvariable, variable (1):name_1, variable (2, 3):name_2, variable(3, 1, 2):name_3, and so on....
```

I want to retrieve after checking the Main keyword exist in the particular line and then get the corresponding information.

For example if I have variable (1) in a particular line in another file. I want to get the answer as name_1

Input file

```
variable (1)
variable (3,1,2)
variable (1) as so on...
```

Required output:

```
name_1
name_3
name_1 and so on..
```

code till now:

```
print("\n-- ACCESSED VARIABLES --\n")
with open(commands_file, "r") as find_feature_access:
    with open("commands_analysis/feature_commands", "a") as feature_commands:
        with open("common_files/commands_library", "r") as feature_names:
            for line_1 in find_feature_access:
                current_line = line_1.strip()
                if current_line in possible_variables:
                    feature_commands.write(current_line + "\n")
                    for line_2 in feature_names:
                        if current_line in line_2:
                            line_part = line_2.strip(",")
                            if current_line in line_part:
                                required_part = line_part.strip(",")
                                print (required_part)
```

Comment: Your example input file doesn't match your format description. And in your code, `possible_variables` is undefined.

Comment: In the input line `variable (3,1,2)`, are 1 and 2 just to be ignored? So only the first number is used?

Comment: @Evert Not exactly variable (3,1,2) corresponds to the name_3 its nothing to be ignored.Its just hardcoded in a text file.

Comment: Do you have two input files? One format file, and one actual input file?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
sFILE = 'Main keyword:Mainvariable, variable (1):name_1, variable (2, 3):name_2, variable(3, 1, 2):name_3'

# I'm removing the beginning, but you could extract it if you want to check it
# ie "Main keyword:Mainvariable,"
sLINE = sFILE[26:]
# split the rest of the line at "variable"
sVARS = sLINE.split('variable')

for item in sVARS:
  # clean up whitespaces and commas
  item = item.strip(' ,')
  print('"',item,'"')

# prints "(1):name_1"
# prints "(2, 3):name_2"
# prints "(3, 1, 2):name_3"
```

Now you can extract the name_n or do some other necessary operation or do the same thing in your other file and cross check? eg populate the names in a list (or dic depending on your need) and then in the other file extract the "1" "2" and "3" and look up the list/dictionary?